# Javascript - jQuery preventDefault method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a javascript noob, so apologies if this question is not for this forum. I am trying to understand jQuery method:

> e.preventDefault()

In the code below, when moving items form one list to another it is needed for us to be able to move the items. I would like to know what exactly is happening there and what default action are we preventing from happening?

```
 $('#move').click(
  function(e) {
    $('#list1 > option:selected').appendTo('#list2');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

$('#moveAll').click(
function(e) {
  $('#list1 > option').appendTo('#list2');
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('#removeAll').click(
  function(e) {
    $('#list2 > option').appendTo('#list1');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ Read the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well basically when you click hyperlink it posts back to url or `#`
When we add `e.preventDefault()` function, jQuery will prevent default action of click event.

Therefore when you click `#move`, page will not refresh but action within function will be executed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, this confused me a bit since my hyperlink had an empty href="" so I thought it wouldn't refresh the page anyway, thanks again for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It will prevent further default action for current event.

E.g. clicking on link will follow `href` of element. `e.preventDefault();` will prevent following link and you will not be redirected.

More information [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#a1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert('Clicked, but not following link.');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com" id="a1">Link with preventDefault</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://google.com" id="a2">Link without preventDefault</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `e.preventDefault()` should be first line when defining what all things will happen in function.

```
 $('#move').click(
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#list1 > option:selected').appendTo('#list2');
  });

$('#moveAll').click(
function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#list1 > option').appendTo('#list2');
});

$('#removeAll').click(
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#list2 > option').appendTo('#list1');
  });
```

Secondly `preventDefault` prevents the default function of element to which it is applied.

**For ex:**

```
<a href="#" class="clickBtn">
```

If you fire event on above `<a>` by default it will take to document to top and will show a `#` in url and then fire you function but if you use `preventDefault` then its default function of linking will be prevented.